# 100% height on body and html, but I still can't set height on divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a double column html setup using Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row fullHeight">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-side">
            <img src="assets/images/favicon.ico" class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>

                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">API Credentials</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Authentication</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Best Practices</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Pagination</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Rate Limits</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Time</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Webhooks</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">API Reference</a></li>

                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Lock</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">LockCommand</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">LockEvent</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">OAuth Token</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">User</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-10">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 leftSide">
                <h1>Description</h1>
                <h3>Returns information about the current user</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 rightSide">
                <h1>Method</h1>
                <h3>Get</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 rightSide">
                <h1>URL</h1>
                <h3>/me</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 leftSide">
                <h4>Request Properties</h4>
                <p>None</p>
                <h4>Response Properties</h4>
                <p>Returns a <a href="#" class="modalLink">User</a> object</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 rightSide">
                <h4>Example Request</h4>
                <pre>GET /me</pre>
                <h4>Example Response</h4>
                <pre>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</pre>
                <pre id="_me"></pre>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why my second .leftSide div is not going the full height of its parent row with the CSS styling I currently have:

```
html, body, .row {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.leftSide {
  background-color: #00a3da;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%
}

.rightSide {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%
}
```

I can give a specific height, but I want it to be responsive. I have tried finding the answer and most posts say to make sure that the parent div has a height. I tried to make sure that all possible parents had a height, so what am I missing? Thanks in advance for any help! :)

EDIT *** Here is a JS fiddle of where I currently am: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25309/

I have the heights matching now, but they are taking up the whole page instead of just what the rows height was originally. Is there a way around this so that the height is the same size as the longest column in the row's content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first row is obeying the height as you have the same set of `elements` and that comes with the same set of `styles`.

[image: First Row]

But this is not the case with second `row`. You have composite set of elements in first and second column which comes with different set of `styles` and the height varies accordingly.

[image: Second Row]

Suggestions and solutions:

- Either style the elements in both columns in the second `row` to make sure that their parent row take same height (not good as it may result in issues in future)
- Manage the size using `JavaScript` (not recommended as our first approach here should be `CSS`)
- [Flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- Make the row think it is a table; set `display: table` to `row` and `display: table-cell` to `col-`
- `.row-eq-height` using [Flexbox](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/)
- Make sure that the first / second column have a **predefined height**.
- Set a new class, say, `row2` to second row and set a `min-height` like below

Markup:

```
<div class="row row2">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 leftSide">
        <h4>Request Properties</h4>
        <p>None</p>
        <h4>Response Properties</h4>
        <p>Returns a <a href="#" class="modalLink">User</a> object</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 rightSide">
        <h4>Example Request</h4>
        <pre>GET /me</pre>
        <h4>Example Response</h4>
        <pre>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</pre>
        <pre id="_me"></pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.row2 > * {
    min-height: 190px;
}
```

Full Markup if anyone want to experiment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap Height Test</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        html, body, .row {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .leftSide {
            background-color: #00a3da;
            color: white;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        .rightSide {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        .row2 > * {
            min-height: 190px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row fullHeight">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-side">
                    <img src="assets/images/favicon.ico" class="logo">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>

                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">API Credentials</a></li>
                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Authentication</a></li>
                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Best Practices</a></li>
                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Pagination</a></li>
                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Rate Limits</a></li>
                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Time</a></li>
                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Webhooks</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#">API Reference</a></li>

                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Lock</a></li>
                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">LockCommand</a></li>
                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">LockEvent</a></li>
                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">OAuth Token</a></li>
                        <li class="subLi"><a href="#">User</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-10">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 leftSide">
                        <h1>Description</h1>
                        <h3>Returns information about the current user</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 rightSide">
                        <h1>Method</h1>
                        <h3>Get</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 rightSide">
                        <h1>URL</h1>
                        <h3>/me</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 leftSide">
                        <h4>Request Properties</h4>
                        <p>None</p>
                        <h4>Response Properties</h4>
                        <p>Returns a <a href="#" class="modalLink">User</a> object</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 rightSide">
                        <h4>Example Request</h4>
                        <pre>GET /me</pre>
                        <h4>Example Response</h4>
                        <pre>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</pre>
                        <pre id="_me"></pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would I make the predefined height the same height as the content in the largest row?

Comment: Can't we solve it using a `min-height` as mentioned above?

Comment: Thanks, @L J. This works as long as the right side is that height, but if I add anything in the right column it will throw them off again.

Answer (score 3):

To get the `.leftside` to go to 100% height, you need to set `height:100%` for all parent divs. I added 'style="height:100%"' to `.container-fluid`,`.col-sm-9 .col-lg-10` Try using:

```
<style>
html, body, .row {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.leftSide {
  background-color: #00a3da;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%
}

.rightSide {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%
}
```

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%">
<div class="row fullHeight" style="height:100%">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-side">
            <img src="assets/images/favicon.ico" class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>

                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">API Credentials</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Authentication</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Best Practices</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Pagination</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Rate Limits</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Time</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Webhooks</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">API Reference</a></li>

                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">Lock</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">LockCommand</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">LockEvent</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">OAuth Token</a></li>
                <li class="subLi"><a href="#">User</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-10" style="height:100%">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 leftSide">
                <h1>Description</h1>
                <h3>Returns information about the current user</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 rightSide">
                <h1>Method</h1>
                <h3>Get</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 rightSide">
                <h1>URL</h1>
                <h3>/me</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 leftSide">
                <h4>Request Properties</h4>
                <p>None</p>
                <h4>Response Properties</h4>
                <p>Returns a <a href="#" class="modalLink">User</a> object</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 rightSide">
                <h4>Example Request</h4>
                <pre>GET /me</pre>
                <h4>Example Response</h4>
                <pre>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</pre>
                <pre id="_me"></pre>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Samuel Denty, but when I changed "<div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-10" style="height:100%">" the height wouldn't budge. :(

Comment: @RobertPrine could you provide a live example on jdFiddle or online?

Answer (score 1):

**All** parent elements of the rightSide and leftSide must have the heights declared. Try setting the height: 100% on the div as well

```
<div style="height: 100%" class="col-sm-9 col-lg-10">
```

Comment: I missed that one! Thank you for the suggestion, @Stormhashe, but it still didn't fix it when I made the change. :(

Comment: Did you check all the parent elements? keep checking up the tree to see if you missed some element. is that website online? I could try looking at your website to check whats the problem

Comment: I missed <div class="container-fluid"> too, but when I added height 100% to it all of my divs became the height of the page. How would I just get the height to match the rows height?

Comment: try adding height: auto to the rows div

Comment: When I change the .row height to auto it makes it go back to uneven.

Comment: it get set to uneven because the height gets adjusted by the content height. to solve that, you need to add a minimum height to the div.

    min-height: 50px for example

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're wanting .leftSide to be the full height of it's row? Or you want .leftSide to touch the the bottom of your navbar?

Either way the issue is margins. On your H1s you have margins like so:

```
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

If you change them to:

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

you'll solve the first scenario. To get leftSide to touch the navbar div you'll need to remove the margin: bottom on it. If you don't want to change the header margins you can wrap a div around it and add enough padding to remove the whitespace. Or you can selectively target that specific H1.